# How to check which python version is supposed to use

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Put the case that I have a bunch of python scripts all beginning either with `#!/usr/bin/env python` or with nothing (no shebang at all). Some of those scripts need python `2.7` (or any `2.x` version), some of them need python `3.x` and some of them can run on both (these check the python version themselves).

I am on a system with two versions of python: `python2` and `python3`. The general `python` programm is just a symlink.

As this `python` symlink can change I want to edit the shebangs in the scripts to specify if this script should use `python2` or `python3`. Is there any possibility/program/script to 'parse' a python script and determine if it should get run by `python2` or `python3`?

Comment: Have you tried running `2to3` on the scripts to see if it finds anything? Clear indications might be the use of `print x` instead of `print(x)`. There are other breaking differences between py2 and py3. If `2to3` doesn't complain about anything, it's written for python3.

Comment: @kdopen Is 2to3 an official tool? Or is this an external program?

Comment: Should be installed as part of your python distro. But it's only a rough guide. Really, you need to examine the script in detail looking for things which make it clear which version they were writing for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PEP 394 - The "python" Command on Unix-Like Systems](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/):

> - ... `python` should be used in the shebang line only for scripts that are
>     source compatible with both Python 2 and 3.
> - in preparation for an eventual change in the default version of
>     Python, Python 2 only scripts should either be updated to be source
>     compatible with Python 3 or else to use `python2` in the shebang line.

In general, the same script could be run by both Python 2 and 3. It means that (at least for some scripts) you have to read the source and decide for yourself what Python version should be used.

> Is there any possibility/program/script to 'parse' a python script and
>   determine if it should get run by python2 or python3?

You could try to *compile* your scripts using `python2` and `python3` binaries, try:

```
$ python -mcompileall -h
```

If only `python3` binary can compile a script, you could add `python3` into the shebang.

[Modernize, Futurize, Pylint packages](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) could also help to find `python2`-only, `python3`-only scripts automatically.

[`lib2to3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) allows you to detect `python2` or `python3` markers such the presence of a `print` statement in a source (Python 2 marker) or the presence of `yield from` in a source (Python 3 marker) but it is probably too low level.

Comment: Yep, but I know that most of those 'generic' python scripts are written only for version 2.x

Comment: But I'll try compilation tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

First, put `python2` or `python3` on the `#!` line.  On *nix, when you try to 'execute' file directly, the OS should read the line and select the proper binary.  On Windows, omit 'usr/bin/env and use py.exe to run the file, which is now installed with the PSF CPython installer.  Example: tem.py contains

```
#! python2
import sys; print(sys.version)
```

At command line

```
C:\Users\Terry>py /programs/python34/tem.py
2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

If I change 2 to 3 in file, output changes to 3.4.2.

Comment: The question was, how I can determine what version of python one should use for a specific script. By checking if `print` or `print()` is used for example.